# Edit Column items in ListView

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a listview with several items. There are two columns, one is the name of a product and the other is the the product's price.
Is it possible to change only the prices column when another button is being pressed?

```
string[] arr = new string[2];
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {for (int r = 0; r < num_cols; r++)
        {
         arr[0] = values[0, r];
         ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(arr);
          listView1.Items.Add(lvi);}


private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{          arr[1] = new_value.ToString();
           ListViewItem lvi = new ListViewItem(arr);
           listView1.Items[i] = lvi;
```

Comment: Change how: In code or by the user? The User can only edit the 1st column (although you can change column display order, probably what you want). In code you can change anything. What did you try?

Comment: I want to change it by code. What I have done so far is create an array, and then in one function  I want to import the signals from a file and display the in the listview.
And to the second function I want to calculate and change the values.

Comment: OK, in code you need to access the [SubItems](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.listviewitem.subitems?view=net-5.0) array of each Item. Note that SubItem[0] is the actual Item, ie column 0.. So to change the prive column you can write maybe something like `listView1.Items[i].SubItems[1].Text = yourNewPrice;`